# openshift jenkins CI to produce docker images

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I am using openshift okd and installed Jenkins master from catalogue. A sample project using declariative pipelines (Jenkinsfile) uses docker to execute command. But docker client seems not to be available in jenkins container.

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/app@tmp/durable-e839f204/script.sh: docker: not found
```

Because I am using openshift, I assume docker must be available on host. But Jenkins is a POD without docker client.

Question: What should I do, to use docker images in pipeline scripts?

Installed jenkins docker plugin, but this does not install a docker client to container. While searching on google, I found several articles on Docker-in-Docker (DinD) and Docker-over-Docker.

As workaround I created a separate VM with docker daemon and client binaries. That VM was added as Jenkins Slave. This works, but I think it is oversized. I am looking for a more lightweigt solution.

I assume docker already is available on openshift nodes. Installing Jenkins from openshift catalougue is easy and jenkins is configured to access openshift k8s cluster (cloud settings).

1. why is no docker client available on jenkins master node?
2. what is recommended way to use docker in such cloud setup?
3. Optional: how to scale jenkins worker/slave nodes? I assume it should be possible, to raise number of workers/slave dynamically?

Simple example to run:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
   }
   stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My openshift jenkins should be able to execute such pipelines ...